# How to write query function which selects data according to date interval in SQLite (or Oracle)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, subquery

There is a table of equipment with CATEGORY and BUY_DATE when you bought the product. The question is to display for each day of the month the number of categories that have not been purchased in at least one of the past 5 days (for each 30 days).

The result should be - 30 rows with numbers of such categories.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question also doesn't provide enough information.  There are potentially many, many, many categories in the world.

Answer (score 0):

I would first use a recursive query to generate all the dates from one month ago until today, then, `cross join` it with the list of distinct categories available in the table: this gives you all possible date/category combinations. Finally, we can use `not exists` to filter on tuples for which no record exists in the table for the same category within the last 5 days.

```
with recursive dates(dt) as (
    select date('now') dt
    union all select date(dt, '-1 day') from dates where dt > date('now', '-1 month')
)
select d.dt, c.category
from dates d
cross join (select distinct category from equipments) c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from equipments e
    where e.category = c.category and e.dt >= date(d.dt, '-5 day') and e.dt <= d.dt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by generating a list of all categories and dates and then using window functions and aggregation.  The following should run in both SQLite and Oracle, but assumes that all dates are in the data (with no gaps):

```
with combos as (
      select d.*, c.*,
             (case when e.category is not null then 1 else 0 end) as is_purchase
      from (select distinct date,
                   dense_rank() over (order by date) as seqnum
            from equipment
           ) d cross join
           (select distinct category from equipment) c left join
           (select distinct category, date from equipment) e
           on e.category = c.category and e.date = d.date
     )
select d.date,
       count(*) as num_categories,
       sum(case when most_recent_purchase_seqnum < seqnum - 5 then 1 else 0 end) as num_not_purchased
from (select c.*,
             max(case when is_purchase = 1 then seqnum end) over (partition by category order by date) as most_recent_purchase_seqnum
      from combos c
     ) c
group by d.date;
```

You can include the categories and dates in the CTE using another table (say a categories table or calendar table) or generate the dates using a recursive CTE or another method.  The important point is to get all the combinations.

The subquery in the outer query then gets the most recent sequence number for each purchase and the final query aggregates the values.

By assuming the dates have no gaps and using `dense_rank()` the same code should run in both Oracle and SQLite.